# Antd AutoComplete does not retain input and rerenders as a tiny box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I've attempted updating antd to the latest version... and attempted controlled/uncontrolled ways, but I just cannot seem to understand why this component will simply rerender to a tiny box upon typing in the input.

[GIF of AutoComplete box behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3rVt.gif)

Please find my latest attempt below, I'd be really grateful for some insight;

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AutoComplete } from 'antd';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { withGroupsQuery } from './query';

const AutoCompleteField = props => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(withGroupsQuery, {
        variables: {
            search: search || undefined,
            ...other
        }
    })

    let options = []
    if (data) {
        options = parseGroupNode(data.groups).concat(parseUserNode(data.searchUsers))
    }

    const autoProps = {
        options,
        onSelect: (selected, option) => {
            if (props.onSelect) {
                props.onSelect(selected, option.label, option.group);
            }
        },
        onChange: search => {
            setSearch(search);
        },
        placeholder: props.placeholder,
        value: search,
    };

    return (
        <AutoComplete {...autoProps}/>
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the width. All [examples in antd's documentation](https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/) have an explicit width. Try:

```
 <AutoComplete style={{ width: 200 }} {...autoProps}/>
```